# How to add a splitView to another splitView?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a splitView in which the detailView is TableView and on click of any row another splitView should appear. 
I don't know how to reuse the rootViewCOntroller and detailViewController classes which we get by default when we make a SplitViewBased application.
Please help!!!!